HTML suggestion option doesnt work inside php file (VS Code)
My problem is when I'm writing html code inside a php file, instead of showing html shortcuts it shows php shortcut

I already reinstalled XAMPP. When I use a Windows pc there's no problem. But when I try it on mac the problem above shows.

It would be better if you write the HTML code in .html extension and combine the .php files
